# Finding string in a file

Tags: python, file, io

First timer here with really using files and I/O. I'm running my code through a tester and the tester calls the different files I'm working with through my code. So for this, I'm representing the file as "filename" below and the string I'm looking for in that file as "s". I'm pretty sure I'm going through the lines of the code and searching for the string correctly. This is what I have for that :

```
def locate(filename, s):

    file= open(filename)
    line= file.readlines()
    for s in line:
        if s in line:
            return [line.count]
```

I'm aware the return line isn't correct. How would I return the number of the line that the string I'm looking for is located on as a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the line number:

```
def locate(filename, s):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [i for i, line in enumerate(f, 1) if s in line]
```

In case the searched string can be found from first and third line it will produce following output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Did you mean to return `[i]`? I think you just want `i`?

Comment: Question states that return value should be a list: "return the number of the line that the string I'm looking for is located on as a list". Of course if integer is preferred then it should be `i` as you suggested.

Comment: Ah! I think it is item and index together.

Comment: Could be, difficult to tell since there's no example of preferred output. Line number & line contents would obviously be `return [i, line]`.

Comment: Conclusion. Unclear :P

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about the output. My bad. The examples for outputs that i'm looking for is, for example is the word I'm looking for is on line 1 and 3 the output would be : [1,3]. If on lines 1 , 2 and 3: [1,2,3]

Comment: @Nick Updated On my answer.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for clarification, I've updated my example accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

**Sample Text File**

```
hello hey s hi
hola
s
```

**Code**

```
def locate(filename, letter_to_find):

    locations = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
            for word in line.split(' '):
                if letter_to_find in word:
                    locations.append(line_num)
    return locations
```

**Output**

```
[0, 2]
```

As we can see it shows that the string `s` on lines 0 and 2.
*Note computers start counting at 0*

**Whats going on**

1. Opens the file with read permissions.
2. Iterates over each line, `enumerate`ing them as it goes, and keeping track of the line number in `line_num`.
3. Iterates over each word in the line.
4. If the `letter_to_find` that you passed into the function is in `word`, it appends the `line_num` to `locations`.
5. return `locations`

Answer (score 0):

These are the problem lines

```
for s in line:
    if s in line:
```

you have to read `line` into another variable apart from `s`

```
def locate(filename, s):

    file= open(filename)
    line= file.readlines()
    index = 0;
    for l in line:
        print l;
        index = index + 1
        if s in l:
            return index


print locate("/Temp/s.txt","s")
```